# How to initialize object from class passed as parameter

Tags: python, function, class, oop, object

I am trying to send a class, as an argument, to a function, then create an object of that class within the function, and use that object. However, my attempts resulted in errors.

```
def test(some_class):
    x = some_class() # first attempt
    x = some_class.__init__() # second attempt
```

The first attempt yielded this error: `AttributeError: Table instance has no __call__ method` and the second resulted in this: 
`TypeError: unbound method __init__() must be called with Table instance as first argument (got int instance instead)`.

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first error is telling you that you are passing an instance of the class, and not the class itself, as an argument to your function!  That is why Python is interpreting

```
x = some_class()
```

as a *call* to the instance, and *not as an instantiation* (creation) of the class.

And here is an example of how what you want to do actually works:

```
In [1]: class Table(object):
   ...:     def __init__(self, number):
   ...:         self.number = number
   ...:

In [2]: def test(some_table):
   ...:     x = some_table(5)
   ...:     return x.number == 5
   ...:

In [3]: test(Table)
Out[3]: True
```

I think (but I am guessing here) you have done something along the lines of:

```
In [5]: a_table = Table(10)

In [6]: test(a_table)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-c3b83a3a3118> in <module>()
----> 1 test(a_table)

<ipython-input-2-01a30f6ba7b1> in test(some_table)
      1 def test(some_table):
----> 2     x = some_table(5)
      3     return x.number == 5
      4

TypeError: 'Table' object is not callable
```

Do not create `a_table`, just pass `Table` to your function.

Comment: Always happy to help :)  Would you mind accepting the answer, if it solved the problem?  It shows to others that the solution works.